# term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, client-server

So I have been writing some client server code using multi-threading and I wrote this function:

```
void TriviaServer::accept()
{
           // this accepts the client and create a specific socket from server to this client
    SOCKET client_socket = ::accept(_socket, NULL, NULL);

    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
         throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__);
// make a thread that will handle the new client
    std::thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, this, client_socket);
    t.detach();
}
```

and Visual Studio says the problem is:

> error c2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 argument

I know there is a question with the same name I gave but I failed to see the solution in the answer.

The Handle Client function is declared by the following line:

```
void clientHandler(SOCKET);
```

The error occurred after I changed the line:

```
std::thread t(&TriviaServer::clientHandler, this, client_socket);
```

This function is being called infinity while each time accepting new client and handling him with the clientHandler, this functions located in class called TriviaServer.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I saw this post you are talking about and there is not answer for my question, as I said above.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That doesn't look right.

Comment: @TalSokolinsky Are you sure that's the only line you changed?

Comment: @TalSokolinsky Can you edit this into a [mcve]?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Mind retracting to vote to close as a dupe as well?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'm not sure if it is in the app.  You can do it from the full site by clicking the close link and then the retract button.  Thanks

Comment: @Rakete1111 There was lines about a vector of threads (that didn't work) and I removed it in order to solve the problem by doing so I did solve the problem with the vector but this one was added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::exception`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) doesn't take a `const char*` or a `std::string` as parameter. You will have to use another exception class, like [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error), which provides such a constructor.

You might as well provide your own exception class if you want to.

Comment: I tried changing the exception but it didn't work, even after i deleted the line where i throw the exception the original error stayed.

Comment: @TalSokolinsky Then you'll have to provide a [mcve], because I can't see anything else that wouldn't compile.